# Mocking symfony security with phpunit, return null value instead of bool (not using prophecy)

Tags: symfony, mocking, phpunit

I have a validator that calls multiple methods of the symfony security component.

I am mocking it with phpunit.
The getUser works fine, but I can't seem to return a boolean value with isGranted.
It only works with `willReturn(true)`.

If I use `will($this->returnValueMap($map))` it says:
`TypeError: Return value of Mock_Security_ccdbfb27::isGranted() must be of the type bool, null returned`

if I use `willReturn($this->returnValueMap($map))` I get:
`Method isGranted may not return value of type PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Stub\ReturnValueMap, its return declaration is ": bool"`

Same problem if I try to use a callback.

```php
private function getValidator(string $loggedUserRole, bool $expectsViolation)
    {
        $map = [
            ['ROLE_ADMIN', $loggedUserRole === 'ADMIN'],
            ['ROLE_MANAGER', ($loggedUserRole === 'ADMIN' || $loggedUserRole === 'MANAGER')],
        ];

        $security = $this->createMock(Security::class);
        $security
            ->method('getUser')
            ->willReturn($loggedUserRole === 'ANONYMOUS'? null : (new User()));

        $security
            ->expects($this->any())
            ->method('isGranted')
            ->will($this->returnValueMap($map));

        $validator = new ValidatorClass($security);
        $context = $this->getContext($expectsViolation);
        $validator->initialize($context);
        return $validator;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue.

The 'isGranted' method has a second input parameter (subject) that defaults to 'null'. You have to include this in your parameter map as the second value, the third one will act as the result.

so in your case:

```
$map = [
  ['ROLE_ADMIN', null,  $loggedUserRole === 'ADMIN'],
  ['ROLE_MANAGER', null, ($loggedUserRole === 'ADMIN' || $loggedUserRole === 'MANAGER')],
];
```